# I want to split list of string type and store them in two different list in android

Tags: java

I have this list: `List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();`

This list has data like this: **CBS-DELHI,RBS-JAIPUR,SBS-MEERUT**

Now I want to split this list like this:
**List1=CBS,RBS,SBS**
and
**List2=DELHI,JAIPUR,MEERUT**

But I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `split(regex)` method to split the string around the given `regex`. Here, suppose our `input String` is `CBS-DELHI`. Then we need to break the string when `"-"` is encountered. So, we will use `split("-")` where `"-"` is the `regex`. Whenever `"-"` encountered, String will be split and returned as an array which can then stored in a `String[]` of variable.

Here is the sample code:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class SO1 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
        String arr[]=new String[]{"CBS-DELHI","RBS-JAIPUR","SBS-MEERUT"};

        for(String input:arr) {
            String individual_string[]=input.split("-");
            list1.add(individual_string[0]);
            list2.add(individual_string[1]); 
        }

        System.out.println("Printing List 1");

        for (String s:list1) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println("Printing List 2");

        for (String s:list2) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample output:-

```
Printing List 1
CBS
RBS
SBS
Printing List 2
DELHI
JAIPUR
MEERUT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string.

```
List categories = new ArrayList();
// categories has "CBS-DELHI,RBS-JAIPUR";
List codes = new ArrayList();
List cities = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
  String t[] = categories.get(i).toString().split("-");
  codes.add(t[0]);
  cities.add(t[1]);
}

// codes will contain CBS,RBS
// cities will contain DELHI,JAIPUR
```